# How to add GtkExpander to GtkScrolledWindow?

Tags: c, gtk

I have some code like this:

```
GtkWidget *scrollWin;

void appendDataToWindow(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data)
{
    GtkWidget *expander;
    expander = gtk_expander_new("GET somepage.html  200 OK   100K");
    gtk_scrolled_window_add_with_viewport(GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW(scrollWin), 
                                          expander);
}

int main()
{
    // initialize a window
    // add a vbox to the window
    scrollWin = gtk_scrolled_window_new(NULL, NULL);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox), scrollWin, FALSE, TRUE, 5);
    // add a button to the vbox
    // when the button is clicked, appendDataToWindow will be called

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
    gtk_main();
    return 0;
}
```

What I want to do is that when the button is clicked, a new GtkExpander will be added to the scrolled window, but it doesn't work.. Any suggestions will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're just missing some gtk_widget_show() calls

Answer (score 0):

Looks good, but you seem to be missing the button creation:

```
GtkWidget *button;

button = gtk_button_new_with_label("Click me");
g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(button), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(appendDataToWindow), scrollWin);
```

Add code to pack the button into your window as required, and then change the callback (`appendDataToWindow`) to expect the scrolled window widget pointer in the `data` argument, so that `scrollWin` doesn't have to be a global.